# ?format=html is appended to the URL on a multilingual website

Tags: multilingual, format

Problem with adding ?format=html has been going on since joomla 4. The problem occurs when there are language connections between materials, but the problem could be solved using this principle:.../plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php add line 451
[image]

How the problem was solved is described in more detail here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/39181#issuecomment-1336349300

But after switching to joomla 5, this method no longer works. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Hello @Sergei, can you describe for us what additional steps you may have tried in order to resolve the issue in Joomla 5? That may help garner some additional attention to your question. Welcome to the JSE.

Comment: Hello. @TerryCarter, I tried to follow all the steps according to the instructions here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/39181#issuecomment-1336349300
Previously, following these steps helped in solving the problem in joomla 3 and joomla 4. But in joomla 5 this no longer works.